Chrome becomes unresponsive when entering breakpoint
I have an issue with debugging JavaScript code in Chrome.

My JavaScript code doesn't have an infinite loop or any other performance issues, according to the Chrome performance tab. But when the breakpoint is triggered, I can't click anything in DevTools, nor on the page. I can still change tabs.

The only solution I have is closing the tab and debugging manually with console.log to see what is wrong. I can't use DevTools breakpoints for debugging.
My Chrome version: Version 127.0.6533.89 (Official Build) (64-bit)
All extensions are removed, and all settings are set to their defaults, but the debugger is still unresponsive.

Chrome canary seems to work (v.129)

I found a temporary fix that works for me. the issue happened when I was working on localhost:4200, I switched to localhost:5000 and have no issues so far. my team mate says this doesn't work for him, so maybe it doesn't work for everyone.
my chrome version is 127.0.6533.89 (Official Build) (64-bit).
Update: we found out that chrome version 127 has this issue. chrome canary works fine. I use firefox for now until chrome is fixed, it's not as easy as chrome but good enough.

Exactly, got this issue in Chrome 127,

Yes, this issue appears to be present in Chrome version 127. The browser becomes completely unresponsive whenever the execution flow hits a breakpoint. Once this happens, it's almost impossible to interact with DevTools, including removing the breakpoints. I've also noticed the same behavior in Microsoft Edge, which suggests this might be a Chromium-level issue rather than something specific to Chrome alone.
For now, using Chrome Canary or switching to another browser like Firefox might be the best workaround until this is resolved in a future update.

I confirm that I have the same issue on Microsoft Edge as well. The debugger freezes on a breakpoint hit and makes the tab unresponsive. I am on Edge 127.0.2651.105 ARM64 MacOS 14.5.
Switched to Chrome Canary 129.0.6659.0 and it fixed the issue.
